# Update $scope, digest in progress

Tags: angularjs

This is asked and answered many times already. 
But, after trying many things, I still have this problem.

I have single page with a search button in Angular. The parameter is getting trough fine and logged like this `console.log("searched: " + search.term);`

Then I use this term to query my database using REST, the result is coming back fine. All good!

Now, I'd like to update the $scope data with these new results. I have treid to do that by adding `$scope.$apply()` and by using `$timeout` and by using `$digest`.

It all leads me to the error: **$digest already in progress**

Then I used $scope.$watch and that works, I tested it with alerts but the data never ever changes in my browser.

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('Grep GUI', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.view1',
  'myApp.view2',
  'myApp.version'
]).
config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]).
controller('DataBeest', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('http://localhost:8529/_db/grep/grepdata/huizen').
            then(function(response) {
                $scope.greeting = response.data;
            });

    $scope.search = function(search) {
      console.log("searched: " + search.term);

      $http.get('http://localhost:8529/_db/grep/zoek/zoek/' + search.term).
        then(function(response) {
                    $scope.greeting = response.data;
                    $scope.$digest()
        });
    }
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en" ng-app="grep GUI" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  <script src="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">

      <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="/" title="grep Crawler">/Grand Theft grep</a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="/alle_data">/alle_data</a></li>
              <li><a href="/alle_plaatjes">/alle_plaatjes</a></li>
              <li><a href="/nog_wat">/nog_wat</a></li>
          </ul>

          <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right"  ng-controller="DataBeest">
          <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
          <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Zoek" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" ng-model="search.term">
              <div class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ng-click="search(search)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
              </div>
          </div>
          </form>
          </div>

      </div>

  </div>

<div class="container" ng-controller="DataBeest">
  {{ greeting }}
</div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're using a native angular AJAX using the `$http` service, so why do you need `$scope.$digest()`?

Comment: I think you can remove $scope.$digest() and you should be able to see the modified values under greeting

Comment: `$scope.$apply` or `$scope.$digest` shouldn't be necessary here.  You only need these if you are updating data without angular's knowledge.  It looks like your problem is more with the response in your search;  have you logged it to verify it has the data you are expecting?

Comment: And if you must use the unnecessary `$scope.$digest()` as you do at the moment, you can try `$timeout` instead, but again - You don't need it with your current code

Comment: I was also thinking this should be going 'automagically' both REST calls return data in the same format so that should be ok, tested with Postman. But when I log the response.data it looks like I only have the first object of the array. I will rewrite the view and then update my question.

Comment: ok found it, I had re-used the controller in the view, this made it all wonky..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok found it, I had re-used the controller in the view, this made it all wonky..